# Pass value from ASPX page to code behind through a link or button

Tags: asp.net, parameters, hyperlink, webforms

I have the code:

```
<a href="#" runat="server" onServerClick="Test">Test Link</a></div>
```

And code behind is:

```
    protected void Test(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

What I want is to send an assumed value like <%Eval("testdata")%> to Test()
that I can execute some code like updating database base on <%Eval("testdata")%>, and the Page is not redirected to another one.
(So I dont use Request.QueryString)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a link button for your use case.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Test" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("testdata"%>' OnClick="Test"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then in your code behind.

```
protected void test (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var linkButton = (LinkButtone)sender;
    var argument = linkButton.CommandArgument;
    ......
}
```